# how to correctly compare unicode string from psycopg2 in Python?

Tags: python, string, unicode, utf-8, psycopg2

I have a problem with comparing a UTF-8 string obtained from PostgreSQL database:

```
>>> db_conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='foo' user='foo' host='localhost' password='xxx'")
>>> db_cursor = db_conn.cursor()
>>> sql_com = ("""SELECT my_text FROM table WHERE id = 1""")
>>> db_cursor.execute(sql_com)
>>> sql_result = db_cursor.fetchone()
>>> db_conn.commit()
>>> db_conn.close()
>>> a = sql_result[0]
>>> a
u'M\xfcnchen'
>>> type(a)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> print a
München
>>> b = u'München'
>>> type(b)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> print b
MÃ¼nchen
>>> a == b
False
```

I am really confused why is this so, I can someone tell me how should I compare a string with an Umlaut from the database to another string, so the comparison is true? My database is UTF8:

```
postgres@localhost:$ psql -l
        List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding 
-----------+----------+----------
 foo       | foo      | UTF8
```

Comment: What is you sys.stdout.encoding and sys.stdin.encoding?

Comment: Assuming your console encoding is utf8, you should actually use `b = 'München'.decode('utf8')` to get what you expect.

Answer (score 3):

This is clearly a problem with locale of your console.

`u"München"` is `u'M\xfcnchen'` in Unicode and `'M\xc3\xbcnchen'` in UTF-8. That latter is your `MÃ¼nchen` if taken as ISO8859-1 or CP1252.

Psycopg2 seems to supply you with correct Unicode values, as it should.

Comment: Hmm, so is mine. Look at the value of `sys.stdin.encoding` and `sys.stdout.encoding`, both should be 'UTF-8'. Maybe try another terminal emulator. For some reason, your terminal and the Python interpreter see the same string 'München' encoded differently.

Answer (score 1):

If you type

```
b = 'München'
```

What do you get from type(b) ??

Maybe you don't need to literally transform the string into unicode text as Python will automatically note this.

EDIT: I get this from my python CLI:

```
>>> b = u'München'
>>> b
u'M\xfcnchen'
>>> print b
München
```

While you are gettin' your print result in a different encoding

Comment: >>> b = 'München'
>>> type(b)
<type 'str'>
>>>

Comment: My locale is en_US.UTF-8, and when I just type b and press enter I get: u'M\xc3\xbcnchen', not u'M\xfcnchen'. But on a different machine I get u'M\xfcnchen'. I don't understand this at all, why its different on the second machine? Can it be because the first machine has Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Jan 24 2010, 14:53:14) and the second Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec 26 2010, 22:31:48)?